# pass string with HTML to send_keys in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have problems when I pass a string to send_keys that contains HTML. It all shifts. For example `<tag>abc</tag>def` becomes `<tag>c</tagdef>`. The text-field is described by:

```
<textarea maxlength="4000" id="some-id" rows="3" name="data[a][b]" class="a-form-normal" dir="auto" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

I don't really understand what happens and how I can avoid it. I normally pass my html-string with:
`description = '<tag>abc</tag>def'
browser.find_element_by_id('some-id).send_keys(description)`
This results in the strange shifts, described above.

Instead I tried to paste the string instead:

```
os.system("echo %s| clip" % description.strip())
browser.find_element_by_id('some-id').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')
```

Then I get the error message: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I am using Python 3.7 on a Raspberry Pi

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Could you add the html of the text field this text is being sent too?

Comment: @Jortega added `<textarea maxlength="4000" id="some-id" rows="3" name="data[a][b]" class="a-form-normal" dir="auto" spellcheck="true"></textarea>`

Answer (score 2):

Got it solved by using a different way to copy to clipboard:

```
import pyperclip

description = '<tag>abc</tag>def'
pyperclip.copy(description)
browser.find_element_by_id('some-id').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')
```

But a way without clipboard is still missing ...